# Do I remove eldritch tokens placed on the board after a mystery that placed them is solved?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Some mysteries will require you to place eldritch tokens on various spaces. When such a mystery is solved, do you remove the eldritch tokens placed by that mystery?  I have concluded that the tokens are meant to be used generically across cards and effects that cause them to appear, so my thinking is that the answer is "no, they remain on the board, even if they currently have no meaning."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Reference guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), page 8:

> When the active Mystery is solved or removed from play, discard 
>   all tokens on it or placed by it. Then draw a new Mystery, placing 
>   it on top of any solved Mysteries.

So, in almost all cases, tokens placed my mysteries would be removed, and then replaced if the next drawn Mystery card requires additional tokens to be placed on the board.

If an individual Mystery card specifies differently, the text on the card supersedes the text in the rules.  E.g., there is a Cthulhu-specific mystery that specifies that all eldritch tokens placed as a result of that card remain even after the mystery is solved.

Comment: Awesome find. The documented line puts into question my earlier post here http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/26993/should-eldritch-tokens-only-be-used-as-tokens-for-the-original-reason-they-were questioning whether eldritch tokens should be able to be interchangeably used when they appear from more than one source. There still isn't mention of mythos cards that place eldritch tokens. (Maybe they never do, I don't remember.)

Comment: It has been a while since I pulled out my copy of Eldritch Horror, but I don't believe that they will only place Eldritch tokens on themselves -- primarily in the case of Rumor cards.  They may place other tokens on the board, but not eldritch tokens, and these are the ones the reference guide refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you remove all the token as soon as the mystery is solved.  They serve no purpose afterwards. They are meant to be used generically iff there is a card that require them.